# `tmux list` sets my shell in an unresponsive state

Tags: ubuntu, bash, tmux

I'm running bash on an ubuntu machine, and trying to list active tmux sessions I tried executing `tmux list` (a non-existant tmux command) that puts my shell in some kind of unresponsive state.

The same unresponsive state occurs if I run `tmux show-option -qvg escape-time`

What happens:

- no output, no new prompt
- pressing ctrl-c, ctrl-d, ctrl-z, just prints

How can I exit this state? The only thing that has worked has been to restart the terminal.

- tmux version: 2.6
- `tmux list-sessions` works fine
- Trying `tmux3.1b list` outputs: `ambiguous command: list, could be: list-buffers, list-clients, list-commands, list-keys, list-panes, list-sessions, list-windows` and then gives me a new prompt.
- The same unresponsive state occurs on other unknown commands, for example: `tmux r`

Comment: Any chance there's an alias or something?  Try `command tmux list`, which hopefully will also give "ambiguous command" since the proper "list-sessions" alias should be `tmux ls`, right?

Comment: `command tmux list` also gives no reply and steals the prompt, same behavior as `tmux list`. What is `command`?

Comment: `command` is a shell builtin.  I'm going to steal from the `fish` shell manpage for it (since fish creates manpages for builtins, unlike some other [shells](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html)) -- *"`command` forces the shell to execute the program COMMANDNAME and ignore any functions or builtins with the same name"*.  It has the same effect in `bash`.  It's just an easy way to make sure the "real" `tmux` is getting executed without anything else getting in the way.

Comment: I guess I should ask what you are *hoping* or expecting will happen when running `tmux list` for starters.  AFAIK, it's not a valid command anyway.  The alias for `tmux list-sessions` is `tmux ls`.  Best case, `tmux list` should give you the same result you saw with `tmux3.1b list`.  Are you just concerned as to why the bad state exists and how to recover?  A valid concern, but I just want to make sure I understand your end-goal here.

Comment: Since `tmux list` is an "ambiguous command" and *should* be returning a message to that effect even under 2.6, I'm curious what happens when you execute any other ambiguous command like `tmux r`?  Just for reference, I pulled up an Ubuntu 18.04 VM with tmux 2.6, and mine has no trouble with `tmux list` returning the "ambiguous command" error.

Comment: I understand the command i non-existant, just curious how to et out of this state. The same thing happens for `tmux r`, no response and the shell is stuck.
`tmux3.1b r` prints: `unknown command: r`

Comment: Does the problem happen (a) when inside a tmux session, (b) from outside the tmux session but while the server is running, (c) from outside the session when the tmux server is not running, or some combination thereof?  If it happens *inside* a session, do any tmux prefix commands work?  E.g. Can you kill the existing window with (assuming the prefix) *Ctrl+b x*?  Create a new window?  Etc.

Comment: Also, what's your prompt function?  It almost seems like the prompt is outputing a terminal escape sequence but failing to close it.  That might explain why the Ctrl+C, etc. just get output when in this state.

Comment: The behavior is the same if I run `tmux gibberish` outside of tmux or inside an already started tmux session. `tmux list-sessions` does not list any sessions but `tmux3.1b lis-sessions` DO list sessions (no matter if they are started with `tmux` or `tmux3`)

Comment: If I print my promp it looks like: `[14:10:59]david@batman:~>`

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I tried to change my PS1, but the problem persists: `export PS1="Potato> "`, `tmux2.6 list` ...